# What's with all the clicking the pros do in the opening minutes of Starcraft games?

Tags: starcraft-2

I've seen this on many streams. 
Are they just running macros?
Hopefully others have noticed this and I'm not hallucinating...

Comment: [Related question on control groups](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18102/why-do-high-level-players-flick-through-control-groups-constantly), which I imagine the reason is similar. I would also take a gander at [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3975/how-to-increase-actions-per-minute/3980#3980), which talks a lot about that. I don't have time to nab all that to post an answer proper, but people can use those links to start from. ♪

Comment: @Grace - I think they qualify as duplicates.

Comment: There was an exact duplicate of this somewhere, but I can't find it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Getting warmed up, fingers moving, blood flowing etc.  I thought it was crazy at first too but after playing over 600 games it really does help and just becomes part of the procedure early game.
2. Raising your APM.  Mostly at the pro level, you will be thought less of if your overall APM is low at the end of the game.  Its strange but thats just the way it is.  Spamming at the beginning of the game just helps to artificially raise it.

Answer (score 7):

Explained in this College Humour video: they are just warming up.

Comment: Please don't just down vote. Some feedback would be nice...

Comment: So I don't know why you were down voted, but I can tell you why I considered it.  Traditionally when we link to off site content we provide summaries of that content.  The reason is two fold, because links do go stale (videos too), and because that content can't be indexed by google to bring the information to people searching for the answers.  Though, I think this questing is a duplicate so I'd rather vote to close than downvote.